# Asset symbol generation in Swift Package

Tags: swift, swiftui, xcode15

I have a Swift Package in my SwiftUI project that includes styles for UI components. Also, this package includes a resource folder that contains assets that can be used in styling. I can get an image by its name but I would like to know if I could access images with enums. Because Xcode 15 automatically generates symbols for assets.

The following example would explain what I mean:

```
public struct CheckboxToggleStyle: ToggleStyle {
@Binding var color: Color

let checked = Image("checkbox-checked", bundle: .module) // ✅ works
let unchecked = Image("checkbox-unchecked", bundle: .module) // ✅ works
let checked = Image(.checkboxChecked) // ❌ failed
let unchecked = Image(.checkboxUnchecked) // ❌ failed

public func makeBody(configuration: Configuration) -> some View {
    (configuration.isOn ? checked : unchecked)
        .renderingMode(.template)
        .foregroundColor(color)
        .onTapGesture {
            withAnimation {
                configuration.isOn.toggle()
            }
        }
}
```

}

Comment: Which version of Swift? for instance release notes for Resolved Issues in Xcode 15 Beta 3 states "Fixed: Asset symbols are now generated for assets in Swift packages. (110083791)" So you may need to update to that version

Comment: It is Swift 5.9 but I use Xcode 15 Beta 1. I'll try with Beta 3

Comment: Did you manage to make it work with the latest Beta ? I am still not able to make it work :/

Comment: No, this issue still persists  @GrzegorzKrukowski

Answer (score -3):

Here's how I do it. If you want more details feel free to look at my package `Iconoir` at https://github.com/iconoir-icons/iconoir-swift/tree/main

Ultimately, what you'll need to do it define an enum of whatever name, and then assign all of the respective `Symbol Names` as strings to the enum, then follow up with a utility method or enum computed property. You could, in theory, also write a script that will automatically grab all symbol names and generate the enum for you, that's what I ended up doing with `Iconoir` as there's no way I'm manually typing 1000+ enum declarations.

#### Enum

```swift
public enum Iconoir: String, CaseIterable {
    case bell = "bell"
```

#### Implementation

```swift
@available(iOS 13, macOS 10.15, *)
public extension Iconoir {
    /// Returns a SwiftUI Image of the Iconoir icon.
    var asImage: Image {
        return Image(self.rawValue, bundle: Bundle.module)
            .renderingMode(.template)
    }
    
    
    /// Returns an image, from the Iconoir bundle, if there is a matching key.
    /// - Parameter string: key that matches iconoir icon.
    /// - Returns: SwiftUI Image
    static func image(from string: String) -> Image {
        return Image(string, bundle: Bundle.module)
            .renderingMode(.template)
    }
}
#endif
```

#### Usage

```swift
Iconoir.bell.asImage
Iconoir.bell.asUIImage
Iconoir.image(from: "bell")
```

#### Other Thoughts

If you don't have too many images, rather than creating an extension like I've done, you can simply add a computed property that does a similar thing, to your enum.

```swift
var image: Image { 
    //... 
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Correct syntax is `Image(resource: .checkboxChecked)` (not `Image(.checkboxChecked)`)

Comment: No it's not. It's `UIImage(resource: .checkboxChecked)` in UIKit but `Image(.checkboxChecked)` in SwiftUI.